# Softphone Layout Pop to Screen Flow

Tags: screen-flow, cti, softphone

I am working on a screen pop feature for a softphone layout.  I have created a screen flow to create a case, but I would like to be able to capture details from the inbound call related matching contact record.  However I am not sure how to capture and pass those variables from the Contact so I can assign them to the new created case record.
[image]

The calls are answered with Genesys Cloud CTI Adapter, and I am not sure if there is a way to get the related single-matching record (contact) details.  It seems like this could be accomplished in a flow  without the need for dev work.  Any advice would be helpful and greatly appreciate.